# would rather have v3 than v3 or would rather have v3 than vinf

Tags: grammar, infinitives, perfect-infinitive

What would be the correct structure for "would rather...than..." in past aspect?

1.) **would rather have v3 than v3** 

    ex. He would rather have gone out than **stayed**.

2.) **would rather have v3 than vinf** 
 
    ex. He would rather have gone out than **stay**.

I have tried to find some references but none exactly match the case.
For example, from the [Cambridge website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner):

> When we want to refer to the past we use *would rather* + *have* + *-ed* form (perfect infinitive without *to*):
>
> *She* ***would rather have spent*** *the money on a holiday.* (The money wasn’t spent on a holiday.)
>
> ***I’d rather have seen*** *it at the cinema than on DVD.* (I saw the film on DVD.)

Comment: I edited your question to use a text quotation rather than a picture. (Pictures are difficult for some people view—and impossible for anybody with a screen reader—and should normally only be used for *additional* clarification.) Anything important to a question should be provided in text.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, do the **v3**s mean anything significant?

Comment: @marcellothearcane: V3 seems to mean the Past participle (_been_, _done_, _walked_ etc). It's one of the terms I have learnt on this site, I assume because it's used in teaching ESL, even though it is unknown to most English speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first example (*would rather have gone out than stayed*) is the more normal. It maintains the parallelism, so that both sides of the comparison are in the same tense

If you use the infinitive *stay*, then what you are comparing is the past infinitive *have gone out* with a present infinitive *stay*. There's nothing ungrammatical about that, but it's rather unusual. I can think of some cases where it is more likely, for example:

> He'd rather have gone out than be here to face his aunt now!

which means something like *he wishes he had gone out ...*. (The reason I think this is more likely is that *be here* is something he is doing right now. One of the meanings of *stay* is the continuing state, including right now; but in contrasting it with *go out*, it is more natural to interpret it as his decision to stay, which presumably happened in the past.

Comment: Thanks, Your advice is very clear and reasonable in the real world. really appreciated !!!

Comment: However; what do you think is the best choice for this exam?  "James didn't go out last night" "But he said he’d rather have gone out ………….. home.”  a) to having stayed b) than stay c) rather than have stayed d)than have stayed  i believe "d) than have stayed" is the best option for two reasons. Firstly, it maintains the parallelism structure (even without "have" omission). Secondly, It use past tense "he said" imply that it should be something he also did in the past so  "than stay" seem not right. But book said "than stay" is the correct choice.

Comment: I woud say "than stayed home", parallelling "gone out".  (Actually I would say "than stayed at home", but that's a different issue).